# How to create method that receive and return generic type?

Tags: c#, .net

How to create method that receive and return generic type?

I have to pass two different types to the same method.

```
  public List<Type1> param1 = new List<Type1>(); 
  public List<Type2> param2 = new List<Type2>();      

   List<Type3> var1 = MergeFoundSigns(param1);

   List<Type4> var2 = MergeFoundSigns(param2); 

  public Type MergeFoundSigns(List<T> param)
  {
     "some logic"
  }
```

Any idea how can I implemet the method above?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know what the types will be:

```
public List<Type1> param1 = new List<Type1>(); 
public List<Type2> param2 = new List<Type2>();      

List<Type3> var1 = MergeFoundSigns<Type1, Type3>(param1);

List<Type4> var2 = MergeFoundSigns<Type2, Type4>(param2); 

public List<TOut> MergeFoundSigns<TIn, TOut>(List<TIn> param)
{
    // some logic
}
```

Comment: Why the members of passed type to the function can't be seen?

Comment: `TIn` can be inferred, but I don't think that `TOut` can be.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
public List<T> MergeFoundSigns<T>(List<T> param)
{
     // ...
}
```

Comment: Parameter and return lists are not of the same type.

Comment: I'd like to know why I did get a downvote though just because I missed a point?

Comment: If you hover over the down arrow, it says "This answer is not useful". Your answer didn't answer the OP's question, rendering it not useful.

Comment: It may not be the correct answer but it's a pointer at the right direction, I don't see a reason why it should be downvoted.

Comment: I'm not trying to be a jerk or anything, but it's incorrect O_o

Comment: Maybe it's harsh  - but I can't change the vote anyway at this point, without an edit.

Comment: Anyways, I personally would not downvote unless it's irrelevant or ahead of a better answer, but I think it's more of a style and there's no real guideline. I respect your decision.

Comment: No, you're probably right. Edit the answer and I will unvote. You've changed my mind :-)

Comment: It's ok, no hard feelings. Upvoted your answer, helping people is the point of the site anyways, the score is just for fun :)